# gmaps no geolocaliza cuando genero mi apk ionic

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic

amigos con este código centro el mapa y geolocalizo, en el navegador funciona todo ok, pero aal general la .apk solo me centra el mapa no me geolocaliza aun teniendo el gps activado

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup) {
    var zocalo = { lat: 11.0041072, lng: -74.80698129999996 }

    var miubicacion = {}
    initMap = function() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: zocalo,
            zoom: 16
        }
        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions)
        $scope.locateme();
    }
    $scope.locateme = function() {
        $ionicLoading.show({});
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {

                miubicacion.lat = pos.coords.latitude;
                miubicacion.lng = pos.coords.longitude;
                $scope.map.setCenter(miubicacion);
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                addMarker();
            },
            function(error) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                console.log("errror");
            })
    }
    addMarker = function() {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: miubicacion,
            title: 'aqui estas ubicado',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP

        })
    }

    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        initMap()
    } else {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    }
})
```

Comment: Algun error que recibes cuando estas desde el dispositivo?

Comment: @sioesi ninguno pero creo que debo darle algunos permiso en el config y no se cuales son

Comment: pero puedes ver los logs? conecta el dispositivo y utiliza chrome://inspect/#devices en google chrome para ver si obtienes alguno, es raro que no funcione en el dispositivo y si en el navegador

Comment: que tienes en tu archivo config.xml?

Comment: los splash los iconos y algunas preference name

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar a tu config.xml

```
<access origin="http://google.com" />
<access origin="https://google.com" />

<!-- Access to the subdomain maps.google.com -->
<access origin="http://maps.google.com" />

<!-- Access to all the subdomains on google.com -->
<access origin="http://*.google.com" />
```

EDIT

Agrega este plugin [geolocation cordova](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation)

EDIT 2

Agrega esto tambien a AndroidManifest, revise mi codigo y lo tengo

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Comment: y no le tengo q agregar algun permiso de geolocalizacion?

Comment: no funciona aun

Comment: En mi caso cuando trabaje con geolocalizacion, agregue el plugin de cordova de geolocalizacion pero más que eso en cuanto a permisos, desconozco!, voy a averiguar

Comment: @FranciscoJoseRodriguezDiaz edite mi respuesta!

Comment: el plugin lo tengo instalado desde el principio

Comment: verificaste los permissions que te deje para el AndroidManifest?

Comment: ya tengo los permisos y aun no

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46945/discussion-between-francisco-jose-rodriguez-diaz-and-sioesi).